# ViewPager на весь экран

Tags: java, android, изображения, view

У меня есть таблица маленьких картинок (100dp) как в галереи. Так вот как при нажатии на картинку выводилася ViewPager на весь экран с изоброжениями и черным фоном. Как это реализовать? Если знаете статьи или что нибудь еще то буду благодарен

Answer (score 2):

ViewPager это View, вы можете поместить его в любой контейнер. Растянуть картинку на весь экран это тип scale у ImageView. На ум сразу приходят два стандартных решения.

1. `Activity + ViewPager` в него передаете массив ссылок на ваши картинки. Настраиваете его под FullScreenMode. Делаете background черным и готово.
2. `FragmentDialog + ViewPager` в материал есть подходящий компонент для такого кейса [Full-screen dialog](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#) на самом деле это обычный диалог с определенными условиями. Очень легко настраивается.
3. `Third-library` я видел на GitHub несколько раз подходящие готовые либы, можете использовать их.

Найти очень легко, вот сходу загуглил мб подойдет https://github.com/alhazmy13/MediaGallery