# ImageView на весь экран

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

Всем привет. Когда нажимаешь на картинку в приложении картинка открываеться в полный рост. Каждый наверно встречал такое. Так вот это делаеться с помощью перехода на новый активити с ImageView на весь экран или как то по другому?

Comment: чем этот вопрос, отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822306/viewpager-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei а как тут  закрыть вопрос. Мне просто не  пришло уведомления что вы ответили и я не знал. Думал по другому сформировать)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего создавать такую ImageView программно, чтобы не мозолила глаза, валяясь в xml-разметке. Более того, вы сможете сделать эффект transition как захотите.

```
ImageView imageView = //делаете inflate или создаете программно.
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).addView(imageView);
```

Таким образом она добавится прямо в декор вью активности